# how to correctly redirect stdouts to pass file without comments to pacman input

Tags: grep, pipe, stdout, pacman

I have a simple file with the following content:

```
# programming 
python
python-pip
perl
# web
firefox
firefox-i18n-es-es
```

The file name for this example will be `file`. I usually use these files that contain packages for `pacman`. In such a way that I pass it to the command:

`pacman -Sy --noconfirm $(<file)`

I don't normally use comments in this file, but I'm starting to see the need for them. No comments (`#`) works without problems, but with them extracts them as packages to install:

```
$ pacman -S $(<file)
[sudo] password for user: 
error: no se ha encontrado el paquete: #
error: no se ha encontrado el paquete: programming
advertencia: python-3.9.1-2 está actualizado -- reinstalándolo
advertencia: python-pip-20.3.1-1 está actualizado -- reinstalándolo
advertencia: perl-5.32.1-1 está actualizado -- reinstalándolo
error: no se ha encontrado el paquete: #
error: no se ha encontrado el paquete: web
advertencia: firefox-85.0.2-1 está actualizado -- reinstalándolo
advertencia: firefox-i18n-es-es-85.0.2-1 está actualizado -- reinstalándolo
```

I have tried to get the `stdout` manipulated without the comment lines:

```
$ cat file | grep -v '^#'
python
python-pip
perl
firefox
firefox-i18n-es-es
```

But I can't figure out how to combine everything:

```
$ pacman -S $(< $(cat file | grep -v '^#'))
-bash: $(cat file | grep -v '^#'): redireccionamiento ambiguo (ambiguous redirection)
error: no se especificaron objetivos (use -h para ayuda)
```

How could I combine it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pacman -S $(grep -v '^#' file)
```

That assumes that `pacman -S $(<file)` does what you want for a file without comments, e.g. using `printf` instead of `pacman`:

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' $(<file)
<#>
<programming>
<python>
<python-pip>
<perl>
<#>
<web>
<firefox>
<firefox-i18n-es-es>

$ printf '<%s>\n' $(grep -v '^#' file)
<python>
<python-pip>
<perl>
<firefox>
<firefox-i18n-es-es>
```

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` could help you:

```
grep -v "^#" file.txt | xargs -I{} apt search --names-only {}
```

Note i use `apt`, but you can sobstitute it with `pacman`.